# Adding an extra glyph (of a character) in a webfont

Tags: html, css, svg, font-face, webfonts

*Please note that the font I'm talking about does **NOT** have Latin characters.*

If you'd go to [this link](http://trdnepal.org/np) **(link defunct)**, you'll be able to see that the whole website is in Devanagari Script, except one character: the capital letter 'S' with Caron (`Š`). This character sadly is unavoidable because the business name itself has this character (ie, the translated Devanagari version of the same).

So what I'm planning to do is edit the font files and add the character in it, but I believe that it's not that easy.

I have tried using other font-face converters, but all of them have this one character missing, which leads me to think the main font itself doesn't have the character. And yet, when I view this webpage locally, the character is present and working, as you can see the comparison below -

*Font when viewed locally*
[image: Font when viewed locally]

*Font when viewed online*
[image]

Additionally, you can view the source code of the following link and search for the character `"Š"` with quotes (You won't find it) -
http://trdnepal.org/np/fonts/mercantile/Mercantile.svg **(link defunct)**

Which means during conversion to `@font-face`, something went wrong. I've tried various `@font-face` generators, none of which is helping.

So, how do I make this work?
Alternatively, is there a better solution?

Comment: Your second link leads to 404 page.

Comment: But the link does not show anything.

Comment: view source will give you the list of characters and their codes. If you look for Š, you won't find it.

Comment: If I understand that correctly, your font is missing one particular unicode character. Do you have a second font supporting that one? Then you could use that as a fallback without having to edit your main font.

Comment: @driftingsteps after couple of experiments on online this font script  `Unicode font Mangal font` gave the correct letter you can test [here](http://www.devanagarifonts.net/tools/romantodevanagari.html)

Comment: @CedricReichenbach There are a few fallbacks, but for one character? I don't think the fonts are smart enough to use an alternative font, ie, if font1 lacks one missing character, font2 will replace it with the corresponding character, but not replace the rest of what font1 characters. Even if font2 did, it would be more logical to remove font1 altogether... which I can't do here, sadly. I used different fonts too, but they had different character map, so yeah. Could it be an issue in the font itself?

Comment: @Webruster These unicode fonts are basically web-safe fonts (Tahoma, Arial, etc) with devanagari characters. I could use this itself, but the content throughout the website has already been written. Still, I'll look for other fonts with the same character map (ref. to my reply above).

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what happens if you write `font-family: a, b, c;`: For each character, it will try `a`, and if that doesn't work, it tries `b` etc. Your problematic character is rendered in one of your fallback fonts, that's why it looks weird.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks, I learnt something new today :) So first off, I need to find a font with the same character mapping and is also serif...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find all of the Devanagari characters (and their unicode char codes) here: http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf

From here you can either copy and paster character 0921 (which I believe is the character you are looking for) into your source - or you can use its unicode representation.

You may need to do some tweaking to have it perfectly line up with your font using a span.

For your reference, the character you need to copy and paste is `ड`.

Here is a screenshot of how the `<h1>` looks with the character copied and pasted in.
[image: Screenshot of H1]
[image: Screenshot of Text]

Comment: This looks exceptionally good... Since the website is CMS based, I'll find a way to replace all the characters this way, hopefully they look better. But honestly this is macgyver-ing to the extreme lol.

Comment: Sure, but please do understand that this might not be my first choice :)

Comment: Hmm. Could you post the whole H1 tag from the working code on your local machine?

Comment: The tag is the same one that you have in the screenshot, with only `Š` in place of span.

Comment: When I do it in photoshop, I get the Š and not the ड - it must be a problem with the font itself.

Comment: The character map for the font doesn't even have the Š character in it http://www.devanagarifonts.net/fonts/Mercantile-Normal

Comment: If you want to add it to the font, you could do that in a font editor - I've done it for a client in the past.

Comment: Did you wind up finding another solution?